# Usage of this sentence whether comma is placed in the right place?

Tags: word-usage

Is it right to say

"updates from the onsite call, we had this morning with the client"
(Updates listed below)

Comment: Can you provide the full sentence? At the moment it as neither a capital letter at the start nor, it would seem, a main verb.

Comment: Despite the temptation to compartmentalise for ease on the eye, use of the comma is incorrect here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect. There are two ways to fix this, depending on the situation:

1. If this is the first time anyone is mentioning the on-site call, replace the comma with "that."
2. If the on-site call is already part of the conversation, and everyone would know what you're talking about if you just said "the call," add "which" after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

The comma should be removed. At its simplest: “the call we had this morning”.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.